# If is in array disable option doesnt work

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried a lot of things `search_array` and `in_array` without success.

Below you see what if I print_r my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 126289214111111
    [1] => 126289214222222
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 12345678
)


$fields="*",$order="",$limit="") {
    $clientsIds = $db->select('clients','','','facebookPageId');

    $clientIdArray = [];
    foreach($clientsIds as $clientsId){
      $clientIdArray[] = $clientsId['facebookPageId'];
    }

    print_r($clientIdArray);
```

So what i want if code below:

```
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="facebookPageId">Facebook pagina ID</label>
                        <select name="facebookPageId" id="facebookPageId" class="form-control">
                          <option>-- Selecteer een pagina --</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach($adminPages as $page){
if(in_array($page['id'],$clientIdArray)){
                          echo '<option value="'.$page['id'].'" disabled>'.$page['name'].'</option>';
}else{
echo '<option value="'.$page['id'].'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';
}
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>
```

What I want is:if `$page['id'] == '126289214111111'` than it needs to be disabled.
What am I missing :(

Comment: ___What am i missing___ Any code that would even Attempt to do what you say you want to do

Comment: I am not even sure you have shown us the right array??? There is certainly nothing in the array called `id` or `name`

Comment: *print_r my array* - which one did you print? Why `$clientIdArray = '';` should be **$clientIdArray = [];**

Comment: So what do you have so far as your html output generated by your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a string based on whatever condition.

```
<?php
foreach($adminPages as $page){
    $disabled = ($page['id'] == $checkValue) ? ' disabled="disabled" ' : null;
    echo '<option value="'.$page['id'].'"' . $disabled . '>'.$page['name'].'</option>'; 
}
```

Right now you are echoing disabled for every option.

Comment: Look closer at the array OP claims to be processing!

Comment: Yeah it's unclear, it looks like that is the array of which the first element is the number he wants to check against and disable if his row id equals it. NWan't entirely sure, hence i just put `($page['id'] == $checkValue)`, he should know what `$checkValue` should be.

Answer (score -1):

```
                foreach($adminPages as $page){
                  $disabled = '';
                  if($page['id'] == '126289214105971') {
                     $disabled = 'disabled';
                  }
                  echo '<option 
                    value="'.$page['id'].'"'.$disabled.'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';   
                }
```

if you verify the string in foreach then you can set a variable disabled and pass that to option

Comment: That's just a longer version of my answer, with a hard coded `$checkValue`

Comment: Also, as soon as one gets disabled, the rest get disabled. Your code doesn't work.

Comment: then put the $disabled = ''; inside foreach, it shouldnt disable all

Comment: i was making my post when you posted, didn't see, sorry

Comment: What my problem is i have more ID's in an array and the code above doesn't workk for me...